# Is it possible to batch remove specific layers with Photoshop Actions?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing, actions, posters

To start with, I have a project where I create a poster each day, and I'm in the process of getting them ready to be sold as prints. Each of the posters that I make for this project has an overlay which essentially says posters number, social links and copyright information (see example below.) I want to offer two versions, one with and one without the overlay (in case people want the poster but not the "branding")

[image: Poster example]

What I'm wondering is if there is a way of making an action that opens the PSD, removes the overlay file (they are all named the same) and then save as a JPEG? I've been experimenting with doing this for an hour or so, but so far I've had no luck.

I'm thinking the process should be:
Open PSD > Remove layer > Save JPEG

Would anyone know of a way of getting this to work?

Thanks for any help you might have!

Answer (score 1):

Put all the text layers in a group.

When making the action, insert and save both .jpg in the same action, save the first .jpg with the text, then hide the text group and save the second jpg:

- ...
- Save as jpg
- Hide Text group
- Save as jpg